# Change related product names via filter in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have my WooCommerce products set up to feed product data to Jet.com the way it needs. That is something like:

```
Product Name - A bunch of attributes - A bunch of other descriptors - Etc.
```

But I don't want the long form titles of products to appear on the website the way they do on Jet.com.

So, using the `woocommerce_cart_item_name` filter, I created a bit of code to grab just the first main name of the product, `Product Name` and display just that in the cart at checkout (it's a combined cart/checkout page).

What I can't figure out is how to do the same for **related** products (upsells and cross-sells) that appear on the cart/checkout page. The WooCommerce docs don't seem to have a specific filter for that, like `woocommerce_related_item_name`.

How do I modify the related product text the same way I do in the cart?

For more context, here's the working cart name truncation code that I want to do the same for with upsell/cross-sell.

```
// Display only short product name on website, leaving long product name for Jet.com to consume
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'shorten_woo_product_title', 10, 2 );
    function shorten_woo_product_title( $title, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
        $_product   = $cart_item['data'] ;
        if ( is_checkout() || is_shop() ) {
            $title = $_product->get_title();
            // Use as the product name the characters up to but not including the first dash character
            $n = 1; // 1st dash
            $pieces = explode(' - ', $title); // Break up the title into an array delimited by the "space dash space" characters
            $shortname = implode(' - ', array_slice($pieces, 0, $n)); // Grab the short name in front of the first dash character
            return $shortname; // Return it back
        } else {
            return $title; // Give the full product name
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  Wordpress native wp_title filter instead. It can affect all titles everywhere in website. So you just add product_type condition to let it affect only products.

```
function change_product_titles( $title, $id = null ) {
    $prod=get_post($id);
    if (!empty($prod->ID) and $prod->post_type=='product' ) {
        return $title.'blablabla';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_product_titles', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks @Elvin85. Using wp_title didn't work in our case. Our store has not used a traditional store setup with product pages as posts with dynamic insertion of WooCommerce product content. Those are static. So the only place we dynamically display product names in WooCommerce's way is on the checkout. get_post($id) doesn't apply there, so using wp_title just makes the cart page blank.