# Customize WooCommerce Product Name everywhere in Frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

i would like to sell Backlinks on Woocommerce. To do so i need to hide the Domain names which i have been saved in WooCommerce Product Titles. Is there a way to manipulate all places where the Product Name get displayed, like in Shop Loop, Checkout Page, Basically everywhere so the customer cant see domain.com and sees instead d****n.com? Maybe there is a Filter or hook or something for that.

I already tried this here [Change related product names via filter in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107855/change-related-product-names-via-filter-in-woocommerce)

But it didn't work on cart, checkout and on ninja tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide WooCommerce product names (or titles), use the following:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'hide_product_title', 10, 2 );
function hide_product_title( $title, $post_id ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    if ( ! is_admin() && ! empty($woocommerce_loop) ) {
        $title = '';
    }
    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_name', 'hide_product_name', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_name', 'hide_product_name', 10, 2 );
function hide_product_name( $name, $product ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $name = '';
    }
    return $name;
}
```

Now **to hide a domain name that is included as a product title everywhere** use the following *(replacing the domain name by stars except first and last characters)*:

```
// Custom function to replace a string (domain name) with a repeating character (a star by default)
function hide_domain_name( $string, $repl_char = '*' ) {
    $index_needle = strpos($string, '.');
    $replacement  = str_repeat($repl_char, ($index_needle > 2 ? $index_needle - 2 : strlen($string) - 1));
    return substr_replace($string, $replacement, 1) . substr($string, ($index_needle > 2 ? $index_needle - 1 : strlen($string) - 1));
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'hide_product_title', 10, 2 );
function hide_product_title( $title; $post_id ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    if ( ! is_admin() && ! empty($woocommerce_loop) ) {
        $title = hide_domain_name( $title );
    }
    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_name', 'hide_product_name', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_name', 'hide_product_name', 10, 2 );
function hide_product_name( $name, $product ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $name = hide_domain_name( $name );
    }
    return $name;
}
```

> Don't forget to make custom permalinks for your products, as the product title (domain name) should appear in it.

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for the nice response. That seams to work perfectly with Woocommerce but unfortunatley not with the Ninja Tables Pro Output. Any ideas how to get it done there?